# Sql Server Management Studio vs. Multi-monitor

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, multiple-monitors

Does Sql Server management studio have no nice support for multi-monitor setups?

The only way I can see to use it multi-monitor is to stretch the main window across both monitors, but this isn't really practical, as my two main monitors are different sizes and resolutions (external monitor on a laptop).

I was hoping for something at least similar to the support added in VS2010. I can't find anything even remotely close though.

Using SSMS 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. 
But you can open multiple instances of it.

Comment: Guess it is a workaround... though requires more system resources of course. Here's looking forward to the next version and hopefully multi-monitor support!

Answer (score 1):

SSMS 2008 is based on visual studio 2008's shell, so it doesn't have the multi-monitor support that VS2010 does. Maybe the next version of SSMS?

Answer (score -3):

if i understood correctly , i dont think even in the next version or any other version. because multimonitor is related to your screen not specific to any software.
regards,
sekhar.